How to Adjust Comparator Output Voltage for Circuit to Work at 3.3V Instead of 5V?
I recreated the IR LED/Photodiode circuit shown in the Circuit Digest article Interfacing IR Sensor Module with Arduino. My interest being to use it to sense/measure RPM of rotating equipment. The article shows the use of a small PCB with the LED and Photodiode attached, and then also provides a circuit diagram for recreating the circuit, e.g.

The only described difference between the components used on the little blue PCB board implementation and in the diagram is the little board uses an LM393 comparator while the diagram uses an LM358. (the LM393 giving a lower output signal voltage). A detailed photo of the PCB board implementation is shown in the link for the article provided above. I have the little blue board as well. It works fine at 3.3V or 5V.
I Want To Power The Circuit at 3.3V
The problem I've run into trying to adapt the circuit to run at 3.3V instead of 5V is the LM358 output voltage is 1.8V instead of the 3.3V obtained using 5V to power the circuit. Not having a EE background this brought up the question:
How Best to Adjust The Output Voltage To 3.3V ?
The IR LED and Photodiode work fine at 3.3V. The issue is the 1.8V output won't quite power the activity LED (using the normal 5mm hobby LEDs). The bigger problem is detecting activity on a GPIO pin. Circuit is Active_Low, so the inactive output is 1.8V and the active output is 0V. However, the Pi GPIO doesn't see 1.8V as high, so the GPIO never detects the logical rising or falling edge from 1.8V to 0v and back to 1.8V.
To solve the LED issue, I just used a NPN transistor in common-collector config to provide 3.3V to the activity LED. (2N2222A with the LM358 output though at 10K resistor to the base) Which works fine. I thought I could use the same approach for the output pin of the comparator, but was unable to make that work. The little blue PCB shown in the article works fine at either 3.3V or 5V input power, and that's starting with the LM393 output of less than 1V high.
Per Comment Here is the Transistor Setup

(note: I've changed the direction of the activity diode, so now the resistor from the 3.3V source is attached at the collector and the positive (anode) of the diode attaches there in the normal common-collector config with the negative side going to ground. It inverted the diode, so now activity is ON and no-activity (output 1.8V into base of transistor) causes Vce to be pulled to ground turning the diode OFF) Basically just moved the resistor over to the collector (by one slot on breadboard, flipped diode around and then provided ground where current resistor is shown providing power to the white/clear diode.
I also thought about using an inverter or nand gate, but the 1.8V I have isn't sufficient to be seen as high according to the datasheets for the 74HC00N or 74HC04N when driven at 3.3V (those are in my scrap box, so I checked).
Is there a simple BJT setup I could use similar to what was used for the activity LED that would work for the LM358 output as well? The easy out is just pull power from the 5V pin on the Pi and it all works fantastic -- but that's not really my goal. I want to understand how to approach biasing the the 1.8V output to the desired 3.3V powering the circuit. I've studied the excellent answer to How can I bias my output voltage after op-amp?, but this is where my lack of a hardware/circuits background leaves me scratching my head. I couldn't see the feedback voltage application to this problem. (could well work, but I couldn't sort it out)
What say the experts? Will a simple transistor circuit do? Or is there a better way to approach the problem? It all seems very simple until your have to make it work on the breadboard...

Raspberry Pi Source Code
For anyone interested in experimenting with interfacing this circuit with the Raspberry Pi1, a C-source and Makefile can be found in the Raspberry Pi Peripheral Access Wtihout root repository under the tst/gpio_v2_ir_snsr subdirectory.

Pi must running the 5.10 kernel or newer (e.g. Debian "Buster" release) for the GPIO_V2 uABI.


I think you need to show how you can use a common-collector NPN to power the activity LED. I'm not getting that bit at all. Common-emitter yes; common-collector no.

An LM358 has a pushpull output and can pull low AND drive high. || BUT An LM393 has an open collector output and CANNOT drive high. To produce a high output level you need a pullup resistor. || See https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm193-n.pdf

Both LM358 AND LM393 have a common mode input range from ground to V+ - 1.5V. When operating from 3V3 that means neither input may be above 3.3-1.5 = 1.8V. || The circuit you show CAN work withing= that limitation but you need to ensure that the design makes it so.

Andy, I added the image showing the current board/transistor/diode setup. Russell, what about adding an additional non-inverting resistor from output back to the (-) input and adjusting the value to change the output voltage gain? I found a discussion Boost Those Weak Voltages with Op Amps, but I'm not certain how that would work with the potentiometer used to vary the level of the (-) input for setting the distance (how far out) the sensor is active?

LM393 is a comparator and while you can affect its gain, that is not its intended use. You will still need a pullup to cause the output to go high. || The LM324 is a linear opamp and also has (as noted) high and low output drive. A resistor from output to inverting input will affect the GAIN but in this case its being used as a comparator (which is legitimate) and you want just high or low output

In all these implementations, don't forget you can swap the op-amp's (or comparator's) inverting and non-inverting inputs to invert its output signal.

Use the same transistor to both power the activity LED and provide the GPIO signal:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The transistor will translate the 0V/+1.8V op-amp output to +3.3V/0V, compatible with the GPIO input.
The LED will still develop significant voltage due to leakage collector current when Q1 is supposed to be off. I use R5 to provide a much lower impedance path for that current, ensuring close to +3.3V output while Q1 is off.
This does invert the GPIO signal, but I figured that won't be a problem, since your software can interpret that signal any way you like.

Using an LM393 is better for a couple of reasons:

It has slight input hysteresis which will help with false transitions due to noise or slow-slewing signals

It will remove the need for the transistor, since it already has one as its open-collector output



simulate this circuit
This will also output 0V or +3.3V, in spite of your observation of the LM393 output being constrained. That's because in my circuit above, there is nothing to load its output to ground, and the output is never required to source current. This is the usual configuration for such open-collector output devices, which are only able to sink current.
For this reason, if you were to replace the LM358 in your own schematic with an LM393, it would fail completely. It would be required to source current via the activity LED to ground, which it simply cannot do. It would be unable to raise output potential at all, in the absence of some "pull-up" element to the positive supply.

Strictly speaking, this configuration is likely to permit the op-amp/comparator inputs to leave their acceptable range. Both the LM358 and LM393 inputs should never get closer than about 1.5V to the positive rail, which would be a +1.8V maximum in this design.
Therefore, to ensure good behaviour, the first thing to do is fully illuminate the photodiode, and adjust R1 to provide about 1.5V at the comparator input. That will constrain the potential at their junction to between 0V and +1.5V.
Then add another resistor (R6 below) to constrain the potentiometer wiper to be between 0V and +1.7V or so:

simulate this circuit
I also added two capacitors. Supply decoupling is by C1 (physically close to the comparator power pins), to help mitigate problems with large output current transients (due to switching the LED). C2 will remove much of the noise and ripple present on the +3.3V power supply.

Thank you. I had looked at this, but got wrapped up thinking thinking this would invert my output signal. But at the solution with the diode was to turn it around and take advantage of the high voltage at the collector when the output is pulled low, this will also work for the GPIO output. I've used a simple pull-up on the output to work powering with 3.3V, but that prevents also powering with 5V as the Pi GPIO pin would be very unhappy with 5V for the inactive state. I'll give this a go and report back.

@DavidC.Rankin With both above solutions, you keep R4 and R5 connected to 3.3V, (so the output stays in range for your GPIO) while still powering the left side by a different voltage rail, like 5V

@Ferrybig, thank you. Yes, I'm still toying with different arrangements. This has been a bit head-spinning to have a handful of comparators and transistors and to arrive at a solution that I'm happy with. Great exercise, the little blue PCB with the LM393 and then the CircuitDigest representation with the LM358 (at 5V done to provide 3.3 as the output) raises a lot of different design questions about "How best?" to approach something like this. I'm quite comfortable on the software C side, but coming up with a simple hardware if-then-else is befuddling for a 5V or 3.3V source. Good stuff!

Simon, thank you! The fog is beginning to clear on the interplay between the comparitor and transistors and the considerations for push-pul v. open collector outputs. That ball of wax is quite a bit to digest all at once. Both you and Glen provided needed insights. I'm going back to recreate the circuit with the LM393 and will see if I'm able to muddle though it with this direction. The circuit is pretty amazing even with the LM358. With nothing more than a small white square of paper scotch taped to one blade a 5000 RPM 38mm fan, the Pi catches every rising/falling edge.

Simon, I created the circuit with the LM393 comparitor and it does work, but I had to add a 100 Ohm resistor in a voltage divider configuration with the 10K resistor going to the - input to the LM393. Replacing with a potentiometer, about 96.4 Ohm seems to be the divider sweet spot. Operating much more than 15 Ohms either side of that and the circuit becomes unresponsive. (either always off or on). The other issue is I'm having difficulty making it as consistent as the LM358 circuit. 10% or so of the rising edges are not seen. (RPM is the same). Any idea where to tweak to get consistency?

@DavidC.Rankin I have no idea what you just said. I'll need a schematic to parse that.

Leave it to an AE to try and explain EE. I'll draw one up.

@DavidC.Rankin I just realised I got the photodiode upside-down. I fixed that now, hope it didn't derail you!

@DavidC.Rankin I'll add some notes about the input constraints on these devices too, perhaps that's what's going wrong.

Oooh, that was the ticket! I wondered about that, but it just shows a small leakage current is all you need. I've swapped it around and now have a good range on R2. Let me hook it back up and see if I can't catch all the edges now. Good thing, I drew a nice circuit on CircuitLab,but haven't got a membership, so I couldn't save or post a link. Will report back and -- Thank You!

@DavidC.Rankin I added a couple of capacitors to help, too. In particular, the power supply decoupling capacitor C1 is really not optional. The circuit may work without it, but you'll likely find the IC's supply dipping and peaking every time the LED switches on or off.

630 Rev at 2348 RPM, caught 630 rising and 630 falling edges. Just perfect. Again, thank you! I'm getting my head wrapped around the differences. I had read a number of op-amp, and comparitor tutorials, and thought I had a good handle on it, but given a breadboard it is obvious I've basically learned how much more I have to learn. This has been a fun exercise. (oh and Yes, I have the 100 uF decoupling cap along with a 22 pF as well - may be overkill on my end, I'll try the 100nF ceramic alone - but good to check :)

Final thoughts. This was an excellent learning experience on why the LM393 comparator provides a better circuit in this case than the LM358. The implementation with the LM393 works perfectly. The only changes made were to swap the inputs to the LM393 to make it active low and to change R4 to 1K to lessen the current draw and tame the blinding clear activity LED. The reflected IR gives good signal from 2-10 cm and does not miss an edge detection at 5000 RPM (tested) and should be good to 20,000 RPM (from article). Thanks again Simon!

@DavidC.Rankin You're welcome

LM358 isn't intended to drive logic inputs (whereas LM393 emulates a logic open-collector output). The manufacturers have little influence over how folks use their products.
If you insist on proceeding with pushing this circuit to completion, the simplest approach may be to add a pull-up resistor to LM358 output pin. As you've discovered, output has trouble reaching the supply voltage, just as Texas Instruments data sheet suggests:
A pull-up resistor might be added between LM358 output pin and the supply pin of the logic device you intend to drive. For example, if you intend to sense LM358 output state with a Raspberry PI, then a pull-up resistor would go to the PI's +3.3V supply. This resistor should be able to make up for LM358's inability to rise above +1.4V (approx).
The pull-up resistor aids reaching logic high, but causes LM358 some difficulty reaching logic low, since its output will have to sink the extra current added by the pull-up resistor. So you cannot make the pull-up too strong (too low resistance). A pull-up resistor to +3.3V of 3300 ohms or more should allow a valid logic-low.
Driving a LED from LM358 output in addition to driving logic is asking too much of LM358 driver output. If a LED indicator is absolutely required (D3, below), it should be driven from a transistor (Q1, R3, below)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Since driving logical outputs was never intended, some effort may be required for the Raspberry PI to interpret its GPIO input logic state. During transitions, logic state may be indeterminate. A proper design would ensure that the comparator output toggles cleanly between its two logical output states.
Engineering such a "fix-up" as this is inferior to a proper comparator device such as LM393. This solution is expedient rather than optimal.

This pretty much nails it. I had drawn from the comment by @RussellMcMahon that I was over-thinking the problem with the 1.8 output voltage and simply needed a pull-up on the output. I added a 51K Ohm pull-up and it worked perfectly. Now this isn't something I'm pushing forward with to create in PCB form, this was an exercise for me. The little blue PCB has a few more components than labeled in the article, one being the little row of resistors or caps that are shown, but not really explained. They must provide something similar. My pull-up isn't a complete solution as GPIO won't like 5V.
